# Not able to access the service

Tags: kubernetes

I have deployed an application to the kubernetes and service exposed of type `NodePort`, howerver I'm not able to access this application.

I have tried accessing the application by using `PUBLIC_IP:32000` but I am getting `site can't be reached`

Note: I have created K8S cluster on my Google servers

```
[root@kmaster kube-ops-view]# kubectl get svc
NAME                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kube-ops-view         NodePort    10.100.137.77   <none>        80:32000/TCP   10m
kube-ops-view-redis   ClusterIP   10.98.40.11     <none>        6379/TCP       10m
kubernetes            ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP        28m
[root@kmaster kube-ops-view]#
```

Comment: What is the public ip that you used? It should be one of the worker nodes ip

Comment: Without more information as to what ingress rules you have configured, it's difficult to advise on why your public IP isn't routing.  You should be able to verify that it's working by navigating to http://kmaster:32000 if you can access it 'locally'.  Check describe of pod and service also for any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in that you also needed to configure service/deployment configuration file and change the selector to match the label in the pod.

If pod has "**app=my-app**" tag, but service selector had "**name=my-app**". Matching them my fixed the access problem.

If the cluster node is somewhere else and you want to make the port available on you local client , then just do **kubectl port forward**:

```
$ kubectl port-forward svc/your-service-name port:port
```